# Appium not detecting menu item on android 7.0

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, aws-device-farm

I'm testing an android app using appium and amazon device farms and some tests are working well in some devices but failing in others

I have two questions:

Does anyone knows why appium is not detecting a menu item on android 7.0? (It is being always visible on the screen and the ID hasn't changed)

Does anyone knows why appium is not detecting any widget in an specific screen but only on one device? (Everithing is visible and has its IDs correctly setted)

The errors happens in the lines where a selector is trying to get an element, this returns a timeout:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("buttonId")));
```

And this returns false because doesn't find the element:

```
boolean emailLabel = ((ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.id("emailAddressCreateAccount"))).size() > 0;
```

These tests are working on other devices (Motorola Nexus 6 with android 6.0, Samsung Galaxy S7 with android 6.0.1) but are not working on a Google Pixel with android 7.0

Comment: What version of Appium are you using locally?
Have you tried taking a dump of the dom tree for the elements present on the screen?

Comment: Appium 1.4.16.1, but I'm not having problems locally, and just a few problems in the device farm, in fact the test are running correctly in 4 out of 5 devices, surely the problem is not with the dom tree of elements/widgets